# Author is changed for the same answer

Tags: support, status-bydesign, merge-accounts, attribution

I got stuck with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14474491/1249581) answer for one question.

Firstly it was this:

> [image]

After 5 minutes it became this:

> [image]

What is going on? How the author was changed? Was that moderated?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This happens when two accounts are merged and the source account (i.e. the one that was merged into another account) was the owner of the post.

Comment: Alright, now I got. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Looking at [his profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/917197/ravinder-singh), He is suspended for voting irregularities. So probably he had more than one account which are merged.